# Unwanted occasional empty item appearing in ListView

Tags: android, listview, empty-list

I have a ListView in which each row is a TextView, and display a line of text. I'm getting a problem where occasionally an unwanted empty row appears. The empty row goes away once list scrolls past that particular area.

I've verified my list rows contain the correct information by using the following code after pausing the app in the debugger. Nothing in the output shows up empty or null, etc.

```
for (int i = 0; i<list.getChildCount(); i++) { 

     System.out.print((TextView) list.getChildAt(i)).getText());
}
```

This shows the information I expected.

I also checked the data backing my Adapter for empty entries, new lines, etc.

My getView() method inside the Adapter is as follows:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView t;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.single_message_row, null);
            t = (TextView) convertView;
            t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            t.setTextSize(mMsgSize);
        }

        else {
            t = (TextView) convertView;
        }

        CharSequence text = get(position);
        t.setText(text);

        return t;
    }
```

Below is an image demonstrating the problem (the area in red):

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any line returns in there? as in texttext\n\n\n\n\n .. This would cause your problem.. Your adapter looks fine

Comment: why dont you simply call `text.toString().trim()`?

Comment: dymmeh: yeah, I'm sure. The messages come from the server and I explicitly refrain from adding \n to the end as there is no need. 

Waqas: Because doing so would remove the text colours

Answer (score 1):

Try after changing getView method as:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
 if(row==null){
  LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
  row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_message_row, parent, false);

 }
  TextView t=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
   t.setText("position "+position);
   t.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
   t.setTextSize(mMsgSize);

   CharSequence text = get(position);
   t.setText(text);


        return row;
}
```

Comment: Mind explaining what you're doing here? I don't see anything here that would fix his issue.

Comment: i think its this line `row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_message_row, parent, false);`

Comment: I will try this change and report back. Just one thing to note - my single_message_row.xml file only contains a textview, so there is no need to do findViewById and cast to a TextView.

Comment: This isn't working I'm afraid, I also checked the data backing my Adapter for empty entries and new lines, all the data was as expected.

Comment: @Al. : thanks for your response if you have any other issue then i'm going to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was caused by using `match_parent` for my TextView width in the ListView. Changing it to `wrap_content` seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For an unwanted empty list item occurring in the `ListView`, I tried this:

```
         List<String> listofItems;
         String strlist=listofItems.get(position);

         if(strlist.isEmpty())
        {
            remove(strlist);
        }
```

'position' is what i got as a parameter in View getView method, because i was implementing a custom adapter.
it worked fine for me!